# Multiple parameter closure argument type not inferred

Tags: scala, compiler-construction, types, programming-languages, type-inference

I have a piece of code that I can't get to behave in the way I'd like. I have a class defined in the following way (stripped down for this):

```
class Behaviour[T](private val rule: Time => T) {
  def map1[U, V](behaviour: Behaviour[U], func: (T, U) => V): Behaviour[V] = {
    new Behaviour(time => func(this.at(time), behaviour.at(time)))
  }
}
```

When playing around with this class I tried to something that I thought would be trivial:

```
val beh = Behaviour(time => 5)
val beh2 = Behaviour(time => 5)
beh.map1(beh2, (a, b) => a + b)
```

For the last line I receive the following error:

```
<console>:13: error: missing parameter type
          beh.map1(beh2, (a, b) => a + b)
                             ^
```

I can of course specify the closure parameter types and it works correctly but why doesn't type inference work here? Of course I could also specify the generic types for the function (see below for both solutions).

I thought Scala carried out a 'scan' to infer types and would see `beh2` and passed into the function and assume `U` here to be `Int`. Is there some way I can fix this without specify the types of the input parameters (for the closure or the generics)?

EDIT: Examples of the two fixes I have:

```
beh.map1[Int, Int](beh2, (a, b) => a + b)
beh.map1(beh2, (a, b : Int) => a + b)
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See [this `scala-debate` thread](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/7083) for a discussion of what's going on here. The problem is that Scala's type inference happens per *parameter list*, not per *parameter*.

As Josh Suereth notes in that thread, there's a good reason for the current approach. If Scala had per-parameter type inference, the compiler couldn't infer an upper bound across types in the same parameter list. Consider the following:

```
trait X
class Y extends X
class Z extends X

val y = new Y
val z = new Z

def f[A](a: A, b: A): (A, A) = (a, b)
def g[A](a: A)(b: A): (A, A) = (a, b)
```

`f(y, z)` works exactly as we'd expect, but `g(y)(z)` gives a type mismatch, since by the time the compiler gets to the second argument list it's already chosen `Y` as the type for `A`.

Answer (score 4):

One of the ways to fix this is to define multiple argument lists. So your `map1` method would be defined like this:

```
def map1[U, V](behaviour: Behaviour[U])(func: (T, U) => V): Behaviour[V] = ...
```

and you can use it like this:

```
beh.map1(beh2)((a, b) => a + b)
beh.map1(beh2)(_ + _)
```

I'm not completely sure why type inference does not work in your case, but I believe that it has something to do with usage of `U` type parameter. You are using it twice - for the first and second argument. It's probably too complicated for compiler to figure it out. In case of 2 argument lists, `U` would be inferred during first argument list compilation, and the second argument list will use already inferred type.

Comment: Thanks very much that works just fine! I'll accept the answer if none can come with an explanation for what's happening in the next day.