# curried function related questions in Scala

Tags: scala

I have several questions related curried function. Here I ask them one-by-one

1) http://twitter.github.com/scala_school/basics.html gives an example of curried function -- I thought it's a function definition, but actually it's not. The REPL does not recognize this as a valid statement at all.

```
multiplyThenFilter { m: Int =>   m * 2 } { n: Int =>   n < 5}
```

2) Why can't we define a function from partially parameterized method? i.e., what's wrong with the following definition?

```
scala> def multiply(m: Int, n: Int): Int = m * n
multiply: (m: Int, n: Int)Int

scala> val timesTwo = multiply(2,_)
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => multiply(2, x$1))
       val timesTwo = multiply(2,_)
                                 ^
```

3) Why can't we make a partially parameterized function curried? i.e., what's wrong with the following definition?

```
scala> (multiply(_,_)).curried
  res13: Int => (Int => Int) = <function1>  // THIS IS OK

scala> (multiply(20,_)).curried
<console>:12: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => multiply(20, x$1))
              (multiply(20,_)).curried
                           ^
```

Comment: 1) It is not valid, cause it must be declared first. For example, like that: `def multiplyThenFilter(a: Int => Int)( b: Int => Boolean) = { List(1,2,3,4).map(a).filter(b) }`

Comment: 1) The multiplyThenFilter is gone now. You weren't the only person confused by it :-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Question 1

The Scala School example *is* confusing—it's definitely not a definition. There's [an issue](https://github.com/twitter/scala_school/issues/29) open for it on GitHub, so maybe it's a bug. You can imagine a reasonable definition might look like this:

```
def multiplyThenFilter(f: Int => Int)(p: Int => Boolean): Int => Option[Int] = {
  i =>
    val j = f(i)
    if (p(j)) Some(j) else None
}
```

(Or, equivalently, `f andThen (Some(_) filter p)`.)

Then the example would be a function that doubles its input and returns the result in a `Some` if it's less than 5, and a `None` otherwise. But nobody knows exactly what the author intended until there's a response to that issue.

---

## Question 2

The reason that your `timesTwo` doesn't work is just that the Scala compiler doesn't support that kind of type inference—see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9118264/334519) and [my answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9119507/334519) for a bit of related detail. You'll need to go with one of the following:

```
def multiply(m: Int, n: Int): Int = m * n    
val timesTwo = multiply(2, _: Int)

def multiply(m: Int)(n: Int): Int = m * n    
val timesTwo = multiply(2) _
```

I.e., if you want type inference here you'll need to use multiple parameter lists. Otherwise you have to help the compiler out with the type.

---

## Question 3

For your third question, assume we've got the following to avoid the issue in your second question:

```
val timesTwo = multiply(2, _: Int)
```

This is a `Function1`, which just doesn't have a `curried` method—you need a `Function2` (or `Function3`, etc.) for that.

It just doesn't make sense to talk about currying a function with a single argument. Currying takes a function with multiple arguments and gives you a function taking a single argument that returns another function (which itself possibly takes a single argument and returns another function, etc.).

Comment: are the two functions 'timesTwo' defined in "val timesTwo = multiply(2, _: Int)" and "val timesTwo = multiply(2) _" in your answer to Question 2 with same type?

Comment: Yes, they're both `Int => Int` (or equivalently `Function1[Int, Int]`).