# Trying to understand spark streaming windowing

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I'm investigating Spark Streaming as a solution for an anti-fraud service I am building, but I am struggling to figure out exactly how to apply it to my use case. The use case is: data from a user session is streamed, and a risk score is calculated for a given user, after 10 seconds of data is collected for that user. I am planning on using a batch interval time of 2 seconds, but need to use data from the full 10 second window. At first, updateStateByKey() seemed to be the perfect solution, as I could build up a UserRisk object using the events the system collects. The trouble is, I am not sure how to tell Spark to stop updating a user after the 10 seconds have passed, as at the 10 second mark, I run our inference engine against the UserRisk object, and persist the result. The other approach is the window transformation. The issue with the window transformation is that I have to dedup data manually, which might be wasteful. Any suggestions on how to tell updateStateByKey to stop reducing on a certain key after an interval of time has passed?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use windowing, you can reduce batch interval to 1s and then in updateStateByKey update also an incremental counter and bypass the update function when it reachs 10.

```
myDstreamByKey.updateStateByKey( (newValues: Seq[Row], runningState: Option[(UserRisk, Int)]) => {
  if(runningState.get._2 < 10){
   Some(( updateUserRisk(runningState.get._1, newValues), runningState.get._2 + 1) )
  }else{
   runningState
  }
} )
```

For semplicity I'm considering the State always a Some, but you have to handle it according your business logic, that I don't know.

In my example Row is as a fake case class that represents your original data and UserRisk is the accumulating state. the updateUserRisk function contains your business logic to update the UserRisk

Answer (score 0):

According to your case, you can try **reduceByKeyAndWindow** Dstream function, It will fulfill your requirement

**Here is sample code in java**

```
JavaPairDStream<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKeyAndWindow(
                new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                    public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                        return i1 + i2;
                    }
                }, new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {
                    public Integer call(Integer i1, Integer i2) {
                        return i1 - i2;
                    }
                }, new Duration(60 * 1000), new Duration(2 * 1000));
```

**Some important links**

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#window-operations

[Spark Streaming Window Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24892704/spark-streaming-window-operation)