# creating Spark Dstreams from log archives

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, streaming

I am new to Spark; looks awesome!

I have gobs of hourly logfiles from different sources, and wanted to create DStreams from them with a sliding window of ~5 minutes to explore correlations.

I'm just wondering what the best approach to accomplish this might be.  Should I chop them up into 5-minute chunks in different directories? How would that naming structure be associated with a particular timeslice across different HDFS directories? Do I implement a filter() method  that knows the log record's embedded timestamp?

suggestions, RTFMs welcomed.

thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 0):

You can use apache Kafka as Dstream source and then you can try reduceByKeyAndWindow Dstream function. It will create a window according your required time

[Trying to understand spark streaming windowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33850605/trying-to-understand-spark-streaming-windowing/33869166#33869166)